# How do you detect which messaging platform MS Bot Framework is responding to?

Tags: botframework

I'd like to be able to give slightly different responses to users depending on whether or not they're on Slack vs. Facebook Messenger vs. SMS, but I'm not sure how to detect what messaging platform a user currently is on.

Is this something that's possible?  I can't seem to find any examples of this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question while digging through some of the sample code:

```
var isSkypeMessage = function (message) {
  return message.source === 'skype';
};
```

You can get the platform that the message is coming from on `session.message.source`.

The value will be one of the following (taken from the [Channel.js source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/3135c25df5e3c5f68c9a86e70eefbab93680c6a1/Node/core/lib/Channel.js#L2-L14)):

```
exports.channels = {
  facebook: 'facebook',
  skype: 'skype',
  telegram: 'telegram',
  kik: 'kik',
  email: 'email',
  slack: 'slack',
  groupme: 'groupme',
  sms: 'sms',
  emulator: 'emulator',
  directline: 'directline',
  console: 'console'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible - see the following sample for how to do it in C#:

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {

        var activity = await result as Activity;
        string msg = activity.Text;

        //setting ChannelID
        string channelID = activity.ChannelId;
        switch (channelID)
        {
            case "skype":
            case "emulator":
            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/resources-identifiers-guide#channel-id

Most of the results of the `.channelID` property are pretty obvious, "slack", "kik", etc. but if a match isn't hitting just debug and see what it returns :)